# Replacing symbol strange situation

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

```
foreach($ret as $object)
{
    $res = $object->...;
    $img_src = $res[0]->src;
    echo $img_src . '<br />';
    echo str_replace("&size=2", "", $img_src) . '<br /><br />';
}
```

`$img_src` ~ `'http://site.com/img.jpg&size=2'`

And I have to receive same link but without `&size=2`. Why doesn't work my last line in code. It shows the same url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you absolutely certain there are any goofy unprintable characters in your source string?  Try debugging with this:

```
printf("%s\n", join(':', str_split($img_src)));
```

And make sure you *really* have &size=2 in your string.  If you see two consecutive colons, you've got something like a \0 or some other character mucking up the works in the middle of your string.

Comment: `h:t:t:p:::/:/:m:d:a:t:a:.:y:a:n:d:e:x:.:n:e:t:/:i:?:p:a:t:h:=:b:0:1:0:8:0:0:1:8:2:4:_:_:L:G:-:-:-:G:0:9:L:H:.:j:p:g:&:a:m:p:;:s:i:z:e:=:2`

Comment: Oh, I see. There is `&amp;size=2`

Comment: Well, there's your answer.  The string you should be looking for isn't "&size=2", it is "&amp;size=2".  (If that's it, please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.)  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work on this end:

```
http://site.com/img.jpg&size=2 
http://site.com/img.jpg
```

from

```
<?php
$img_src = 'http://site.com/img.jpg&size=2';
echo $img_src.'<br />';
echo str_replace("&size=2", "", $img_src).'<br/><br/>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use preg_replace:

```
$c=preg_replace("/&size=2/","",$img_src);
```

**Example of usage**

```
<?php
$sr="http://site.com/img.jpg&size=2";
echo preg_replace("/&size=2/","",$sr);
?>
```

**This will output**

```
http://site.com/img.jpg
```

Comment: Same sitation, both lines output the same url (with &size=2)

Comment: Did this work on your server? If yes then please mark the answer as correct for others to follow.